# How to transfer single element in a list to be list

Tags: python, list

I have

```
[["1","2","3"],["7","6","5"]]
```

expected output:

```
[[[1],[2],[3]],[[7],[6],[5]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension to get this result

```
data = [["1","2","3"],["7","6","5"]]
print [[[int(j)] for j in i] for i in data ]
```

**Output**

```
[[[1], [2], [3]], [[7], [6], [5]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @thefourtheye's method:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [["1","2","3"],["7","6","5"]]
>>> result = [[int(i)] for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)]
>>> result
[[1], [2], [3], [7], [6], [5]]
```

Breaking it down, here is a way using normal loops:

```
result = []
for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l):
    result.append([int(i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function that does not make any assumptions on the input:

```
def list2list(l):
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if type(e) == list: list2list(e)
        else: l[i] = [int(e)] 
    return l

l = [["1","2","3"],["7","6","5"]]
list2list(l)
print l
```

*Produces:*

```
[[[1], [2], [3]], [[7], [6], [5]]]
```

Comment: He wants them as numbers, I believe.

Comment: Also, it's still separated :)

Comment: @aIKid, I think this is the desired output